# Reducing size of Python application using PyInstaller

Tags: python, executable, pyinstaller, minify

I'm working on a real-time plotting application using PyQt5 and PyQtChart (QtCharts). For demonstration purposes, here's my super-simple application:

```
import sys
import numpy
import PyQt5.QtWidgets
import PyQt5.QtChart
import PyQt5.Qt
import PyQt5.QtCore
import PyQt5.QtGui

class Plot(PyQt5.QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        PyQt5.QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self)

        self.time = 0

        self.plot = PyQt5.QtChart.QChart()
        self.plot.setTitle("Plot")

        self.chartView = PyQt5.QtChart.QChartView(self.plot)

        self.series = PyQt5.QtChart.QLineSeries()
        self.plot.addSeries(self.series)
        self.plot.createDefaultAxes()

        self.axisX = self.plot.axisX()
        self.axisX.setRange(0, 100)
        self.axisX.setTitleText("Two")

        self.axisY = self.plot.axisY()
        self.axisY.setRange(0, 10)
        self.axisY.setTitleText("One")

        vBox = PyQt5.QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        vBox.addWidget(self.chartView)
        self.setLayout(vBox)

    def add_point(self, point):
        self.time += 1
        self.series.append(self.time, point)

        if self.time > 100:
            self.axisX.setRange(self.time - 100, self.time)

class MainWindow(PyQt5.QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.plot = Plot()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.plot)

        self.pollTimer = PyQt5.QtCore.QTimer()
        self.pollTimer.setInterval(100)
        self.pollTimer.timeout.connect(self.update_plot)
        self.pollTimer.start()

    def update_plot(self):
        self.plot.add_point(numpy.random.randint(0, 10));

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = PyQt5.QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    mainWindow = MainWindow()

    mainWindow.resize(640, 480)
    mainWindow.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I then bundle the application into an executable with the help from PyInstaller. Here's the .spec file that I'm using:

```
# -*- mode: python -*-

block_cipher = None

a = Analysis(['source\\PyQt5-Plotter.py'],
             pathex=[],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher)

pyz = PYZ(a.pure,
          a.zipped_data,
          cipher=block_cipher)

exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='PyQt5-Plotter',
          debug=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=False)

coll = COLLECT(exe,
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               name='PyQt5-Plotter')
```

Once it finishes, my application is 207 MB, spread across 1,408 files! Seems a bit rough for a 60-line program :) In contract, a simple PyQt5 application (without QtCharts) might be 40 MB across 60 files.

I have no idea why a QtCharts application bundles tonnes of files and massive dll's, such as Qt5WebEngineCore.dll, which on its own is over 50 MB. In fact, if I delete this from the application directory, the program still runs just fine.

So my question is - how would I go about minifiying my application to just what is required? I am aware of PyInstaller exclusions, but sorting through hundreds of files and excluding one at a time would be awful.

Suggestions? Thanks.